# Query only returning two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have constructed a query that joins two tables but the result of the query only returns two columns. Is there anything that is wrong with my query? The help is appreciated.

```
select a.Year, a.RIN
from apcAttribute as a
left join (
   select distinct Amount, TRMasterRIN, AttributeRIN
   from apList
) l on a.RIN = l.AttributeRIN
```

Comment: You are only selecting two columns, so those are the only columns returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main select is

> select a.Year, a.RIN

there are only two columns referenced. if you want something from the joined data, add ",l.field"

Answer (score 2):

Only 2 columns are selected in the query. If you want to display all columns from both the tables use the following query

```
select *
from apcAttribute as a
left join (
   select distinct Amount, TRMasterRIN, AttributeRIN
   from apList
) l on a.RIN = l.AttributeRIN
```

In case you want from the specific table use table `alias.*`.